# How to start a service in the background for downloading a video content in android?

Tags: android, service

I want to download a video content on the click of the sync button. By clicking it, a background service is started to download the content. How do I go for it? Meaning what is the procedure or the best practice or methodologies generally the applications follow to start a service in the bg? Also do I need to use AsyncTask for performing the bg operations?
If so how? Any sample code or tutorial is available? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If your video is hosted so that just by hitting the url in the browser, video starts downloading instead of streaming, you can use a webview and load it with that url.
What will happen next is that the web view will be diminshed by itself as the download will be started and the video will be saved in the default download folder in the hard disk of your phone.
This way you are by passing the headache of managing any thread created by your own to download the video as the andorid itself will take care of the download then.